# ".addEventListener is not a function" why does this error occur?

Tags: javascript, html

I’m getting an ".addEventListener is not a function" error. I am stuck on this:

```
var comment = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
function showComment() {
  var place = document.getElementById('textfield');
  var commentBox = document.createElement('textarea');
  place.appendChild(commentBox);
}
comment.addEventListener('click', showComment, false);
```

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="1">
<input type="button" class="button" value="2">
<div id="textfield">
</div>
```

Comment: You need to put you javascript at the end of the file or use some soft of onload listener. You are looking for `textfield` before its in the DOM.

Comment: Both of the below answers are true.  Your solution is to use both suggestions.

Comment: i want that on both click whatever button1 or button2 comment box should open .

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the your script is executed prior to the html element being available. Because of the that `var comment` is an empty array.

So you should move your script after the html element is available.

Also, `getElementsByClassName` returns html collection, so if you need to add event Listener to an element, you will need to do something like following

```
comment[0].addEventListener('click' , showComment , false ) ;
```

If you want to add event listener to all the elements, then you will need to loop through them

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < comment.length; i++) {
   comment[i].addEventListener('click' , showComment , false ) ; 
}
```

Comment: After so many years the answer is still useful.

Answer (score 43):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an *array* of elements. so may be you want to target a specific index of them: `var comment = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0];` should get you what you want.

***Update #1:***

```
var comments = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
var numComments = comments.length;

function showComment() {
  var place = document.getElementById('textfield');
  var commentBox = document.createElement('textarea');
  place.appendChild(commentBox);
}

for (var i = 0; i < numComments; i++) {
  comments[i].addEventListener('click', showComment, false);
}
```

***Update #2:*** (with `removeEventListener` incorporated as well)

```
var comments = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
var numComments = comments.length;

function showComment(e) {
  var place = document.getElementById('textfield');
  var commentBox = document.createElement('textarea');
  place.appendChild(commentBox);
  for (var i = 0; i < numComments; i++) {
    comments[i].removeEventListener('click', showComment, false);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < numComments; i++) {
  comments[i].addEventListener('click', showComment, false);
}
```

Comment: i want that on both click whatever button1 or button2 comment box should open so i don't add [0] or [1] .

Comment: added an **Update** above.

Comment: @TahirAhmed - Small mistake - In place of ` comments[0]` it should be ` comments[i]`

Comment: if i want to add .removeEventListener on both for box doesn't appear again-again click , should put on in addEvent function

Comment: sorry I didn't get. you want to add `removeEventListener` to the current node comment of once it adds? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: it is like or dislike button whatever button will click , comment box will open, but after again click that box should not open . because it already open first time

Comment: sorry i get it will add in function so .

Comment: @leecarter: added **Update #2** above. highly untested though but it should work.

Answer (score 6):

```js
var comment = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

function showComment() {
  var place = document.getElementById('textfield');
  var commentBox = document.createElement('textarea');
  place.appendChild(commentBox);
}

for (var i in comment) {
  comment[i].onclick = function() {
    showComment();
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="button" value="1">
<input type="button" class="button" value="2">
<div id="textfield"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

The first line of your code returns an array and assigns it to the var comment, when what you want is an element assigned to the var comment...

```
var comment = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
```

So you  are trying to use the method addEventListener() on the array when you need to use the method addEventListener() on the actual element within the array.  You  need to return an element not an array by accessing the element within the array so the var comment itself is assigned an element not an array.

Change...

```
var comment = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
```

to...

```
var comment = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];
```

Answer (score 5):

Another important thing you need to note with **".addEventListener is not a function" error** is that the error might be coming a result of assigning it a wrong object eg consider

```
let myImages = ['images/pic1.jpg','images/pic2.jpg','images/pic3.jpg','images/pic4.jpg','images/pic5.jpg'];
let i = 0;
while(i < myImages.length){
  const newImage = document.createElement('img');
  newImage.setAttribute('src',myImages[i]);
  thumbBar.appendChild(newImage);

 //Code just below will bring the said error 
 myImages[i].addEventListener('click',fullImage);

 //Code just below execute properly 
  newImage.addEventListener('click',fullImage);




  i++;
}
```

In the code Above I am basically assigning images to a div element in my html dynamically using javascript. I've done this by writing the images in an array and looping them through a while loop and adding all of them to the div element.

I've then added a click event listener for all images.

The code **"myImages[i].addEventListener('click',fullImage);"** will give you an error of "addEventListener is not a function" because I am chaining an addEventListener to an array object which does not have the addEventListener() function.

However for the code **"newImage.addEventListener('click',fullImage);"** it executes properly because the newImage object has access the function addEventListener() while the array object does not.

For more clarification follow the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function

Answer (score 3):

**The main reason of this error is this line**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button")
```

Cause the `getElementsByClassName` returns an **array-like object** of all child elements or a collection of elements.

There are two possible **solutions** AFAIK -

1. Treat the variable containing `document.getElementsByClassName("button")` as an array and be specific when using an event listener.
   Example -

   `comment[0].addEventListener('click' , showComment , false )`
2. Use id for selecting that specific element.
   Example-

   `document.getElementById('button')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var comment = document.querySelector("button");
function showComment() {
  var place = document.querySelector('#textfield');
  var commentBox = document.createElement('textarea');
  place.appendChild(commentBox);
}
comment.addEventListener('click', showComment, false);
```

Use `querySelector` instead of `className`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target multiple buttons and add a event listener to all you need to first target all buttons and after use loop for each button

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

buttons.forEach((button)=>{

button.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    console.log("clicked")
})
```

})

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="main.js" defer></script>
```

which makes execute your code after the document fully loaded hence the javascript has complete reference

Comment: ... and still result in the same error because it doesn't answer the question.