# How to window.scrollTo() with a smooth effect

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, css-animations, css-transitions

I can scroll to 200px using the following

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.scrollTo(0,200);
})
```

But I want a smooth scroll effect. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Comment: Just a note for future generations (available from Chrome 61) "The CSSOM View Smooth Scroll API brings native smooth scrolling to the platform through a the scroll-behavior: smooth CSS property or by using the window.scrollTo() DOM scroll method, eliminating the need to implement this behavior with JavaScript"

Comment: Place an empty element in the top of your page, then you can use document.querySelector('your-element').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});

Comment: It is possible to do using. `window.scrollTo({ top: 200, behavior: 'smooth' });` I'd like to add it as anwer but question is closed.

Comment: DOH! US English - behaviour: 'smooth' will get you nowhere...

Answer (score 271, accepted):

## 2023 Update

Now you can use just `window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })` to get the page scrolled with a smooth effect.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('elem');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => window.scrollTo({
  top: 400,
  behavior: 'smooth',
}));
```

```css
#x {
  height: 1000px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id='x'>
  <button id='elem'>Click to scroll</button>
</div>
```

## Older solutions

You can do something like this:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('x');

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var i = 10;
  var int = setInterval(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, i);
    i += 10;
    if (i >= 200) clearInterval(int);
  }, 20);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #3a2613;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<button id='x'>click</button>
```

**ES6** recursive approach:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('elem');

const smoothScroll = (h) => {
  let i = h || 0;
  if (i < 200) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, i);
      smoothScroll(i + 10);
    }, 10);
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => smoothScroll());
```

```css
body {
  background: #9a6432;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<button id='elem'>click</button>
```

Comment: Is this an efficient method?

Comment: For really smooth transitions you rather use `requestAnimationFrame` https://codepen.io/dsheiko/pen/XZEgXW

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Edge at the moment preventing ScrollTo from working: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15534521/

Comment: Safari for OSX seems to ignore the `behavior: 'smooth'` parameter while using `window.scrollTo`.

Comment: @PetrNagy yea `behavior: 'smooth'` also not working on iOS. I think we still need to use the old solution for WebKit on Mac and iOS.

Comment: Is there a way to stop the scrolling before it reaches it's end position? For example, you have a button click to initiate the scroll with a top position of 400. What about another button with a click event to stop the scroll wherever it currently is at it's current point in time? Say while it's scrolling and it's reached 250, you hit the button and it would stop the scroll at 250 instead of the initial 400 you currently set as the top param for the first button?

Comment: @Andrew You mean the solution with recursion? Not the `behavior` method?

Comment: in windows (win 10 edu v1909),  css `scroll-behavior: smooth` is not smooth if you disable `display animations in windows` in control panel. So you have to choose @kinduser 's  **old solution** if you want your smooth scrolling happens in any case

Comment: **but is there any way to set the rate at which it scrolls?** it seems always at some point when you increase the amount of scroll that it becomes "jumpy" instead of smooth :/

Comment: behavior: 'smooth' has never worked for me in any browser. Does this work for anyone?

Comment: If you use `getElementsByClassName` instead `getElementById`, will occur the error: `".addEventListener is not a function"`, to solve it use  `btn[0].addEventListener`. See more in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027935/addeventlistener-is-not-a-function-why-does-this-error-occur)

Comment: to behavior works, use in the CSS `html:focus-within { scroll-behavior: smooth;}`

Comment: `window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })` seems to be working for me on Safari in Jun 2022, macOS Monterey, Safari 15.4

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:1200},'50');
```

You can do this!

Comment: Yes, I'm right with you, but you are using jQuery, and I want using only Vanilla. But I agree with you, with jQuery is more simple

Comment: yes bro. that's only jquery but you can use that. jQuery is very simple.

Comment: Is the problem, jQuery is simple.. And I don't like when is simple. I prefer to go deeper my knowledge in pure JS (Vanilla) and after that I can use jQuery. It's my philosophy

Comment: Not only that but jquery can cause some serious jank when scrolling while changing the height of elements (using `.show()` or `.slideDown()` while using `scrollTop()` for instance). jQuery can be nice for quick/trivial stuff, but it's just a facade for real js. Check this one out! https://pawelgrzybek.com/page-scroll-in-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: 1year after, I think the `scrollTo`are evolved, your script are deprecated for me because now, we can pass an object into `scrollTo` like that : 


`window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });`
And we are the same effect with less line code, and it's supported by old and recent browser :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add on the css

`* {scroll-behavior: smooth;}`
the asterisk prolly means window idk but it works on mine