# Set speed when scroll to top of page

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript function that scrolls to top. How can i modify it in order to choose how slow or fast the page will scroll to top;

```
function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Safari and Opera 
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For IE and Firefox
}
```

Comment: @AlonEitan this answer and commentary should be as famous as cthulhu-parse-html-with-regex http://stackoverflow.com/a/42263472/5087125

Comment: so how should i change my function?