# Scroll smoothly to section

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a smooth scroll with `scrollTo`. I cannot control the speed if I use the option `scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' }`. Hence I use the combination of `performance.now()` and `requestAnimationFrame` to achieve the effect.

It works well on mousewheel event, the problem is that I have three buttons, it should go to the relative section as I click. However it doesn't work for the button.

The mouse wheel event is using the `window.scrollTo(0, startY + distance * progress);` while the button use the `window.scrollTo(0, manualPosition * progress);` where the `manualPosition` is the section position by `lis[index].getBoundingClientRect().top`.

Please try to run the code and click the button, or use mouse wheel to see the effect.

```js
(function () {
    const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.section'),
        btnsNav = document.querySelectorAll('.button'),
        speed = 500;
    let currentSection = 0,
        isScrolling = false;

    function smoothScrollTo(time, direction, mode = 'auto', index = 1) {
        if (isScrolling) {
            return;
        }

        isScrolling = true;

        const start = performance.now(),
            startY = window.scrollY,
            distance =
                direction === 'up' ? -window.innerHeight : window.innerHeight;

        function animateScroll() {
            const now = performance.now(),
                elapsed = now - start,
                progress = elapsed / time,
                manualPosition = lis[index].getBoundingClientRect().top;

            if (mode === 'auto') {
                window.scrollTo(0, startY + distance * progress);
            } else if (mode === 'manual') {
                window.scrollTo(0, manualPosition * progress);
            }

            if (elapsed < time) {
                requestAnimationFrame(animateScroll);
            } else {
                isScrolling = false;
            }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(animateScroll);

        if (direction === 'down') {
            currentSection++;
        } else if (direction === 'up') {
            currentSection--;
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('wheel', function (event) {
        if (event.deltaY > 0 && currentSection < lis.length - 1) {
            smoothScrollTo(speed, 'down');
        } else if (event.deltaY < 0 && currentSection > 0) {
            smoothScrollTo(speed, 'up');
        }
    });

    for (let index = 0; index < btnsNav.length; index++) {
        btnsNav[index].addEventListener('click', function () {
            smoothScrollTo(speed, 'down', 'manual', index);
        });
    }
})();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 10px;
}

.section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.section:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: red;
}

.section:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.section:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <button class="button" type="button">Go to 1</button>
  <button class="button" type="button">Go to 2</button>
  <button class="button" type="button">Go to 3</button>
</div>

<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
```

Comment: Perhaps of interst: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589137/scrollto-speed-duration-setting

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Perhaps it's what I'm looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

## Issues in the code

I found two problems in your code,

1. The btnsNav variable: You have been storing .section in this variable and , attaching the event listener there, which is incorrect. Change it to `.button`

   ```
   btnsNav = document.querySelectorAll('.button'),
   ```
2. When you are calling the `smoothScrollTo` function in the for loop, you are passing `manual` as the `mode`. Passing the mode as auto seems to resolve the issue.

   ```
   smoothScrollTo(speed, 'down', 'auto', index);
   ```

###### Note: There are still some more changes required in the logic which I will leave you to fix as I have been able to go to the required page downwards but the button click does not take us upward to the page. Cheers!

**Hints:** The direction you are passing on the `smoothScrollTo` in the for loop is always down. Instead of using 'up'/'down' I would use `currentSection` and the index being passed to identify whether to scroll up or down. Simplify the logic ;)

## Code with fixes:

```js
(function () {
    const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.button'),
        btnsNav = document.querySelectorAll('.button'),
        speed = 500;
    let currentSection = 0,
        isScrolling = false;

    function smoothScrollTo(time, direction, mode = 'auto', index = 1) {
        if (isScrolling) {
            return;
        }

        isScrolling = true;

        const start = performance.now(),
            startY = window.scrollY,
            distance =
                direction === 'up' ? -window.innerHeight : window.innerHeight;

        function animateScroll() {
            const now = performance.now(),
                elapsed = now - start,
                progress = elapsed / time,
                manualPosition = lis[index].getBoundingClientRect().top;

            if (mode === 'auto') {
                window.scrollTo(0, startY + distance * progress);
            } else if (mode === 'manual') {
                window.scrollTo(0, manualPosition * progress);
            }

            if (elapsed < time) {
                requestAnimationFrame(animateScroll);
            } else {
                isScrolling = false;
            }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(animateScroll);

        if (direction === 'down') {
            currentSection++;
        } else if (direction === 'up') {
            currentSection--;
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('wheel', function (event) {
        if (event.deltaY > 0 && currentSection < lis.length - 1) {
            smoothScrollTo(speed, 'down');
        } else if (event.deltaY < 0 && currentSection > 0) {
            smoothScrollTo(speed, 'up');
        }
    });

    for (let index = 0; index < btnsNav.length; index++) {
        btnsNav[index].addEventListener('click', function () {
            smoothScrollTo(speed, 'down', 'auto', index);
        });
    }
})();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 10px;
}

.section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.section:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: red;
}

.section:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.section:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <button class="button" type="button">Go to 1</button>
  <button class="button" type="button">Go to 2</button>
  <button class="button" type="button">Go to 3</button>
</div>

<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve this effect without any javascript at all - it's possible with HTML + CSS.

There are three steps:

1. Apply `scroll-behavior: smooth` to the document root (ie. the `<html>` element):

```
:root {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

2. Surround each button with a hashfragment link:

```
<a href="#section2"><button class="button" type="button">Go to 2</button></a>
```

3. Add a corresponding `id` to each `.section` to indicate the hashfragment link destinations:

```
<section id="section2" class="section"></section>
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
:root {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

#div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 10px;
}

.section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.section:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: red;
}

.section:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.section:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <a href="#section1"><button class="button" type="button">Go to 1</button></a>
  <a href="#section2"><button class="button" type="button">Go to 2</button></a>
  <a href="#section3"><button class="button" type="button">Go to 3</button></a>
</div>

<section id="section1" class="section"></section>
<section id="section2" class="section"></section>
<section id="section3" class="section"></section>
```

Comment: "*Surround each button with a hashfragment link*" - even better, just **change** the button into a link

Comment: @Bergi Hi, there is no way to control the scrolling speed this way. Like 500ms or 3000ms.

Comment: @KarChung All I'm saying is that there's no need to put a button inside a link. Better style the link to look like your buttons. This does not affect the rest of Rounin's answer though

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the info, my original code doesn't wrap the button inside a link actually. I'm just saying the reason I don't use the `scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' }` is that I cannot control the scrolling speed which is similar to the CSS `scroll-behavior: smooth;`. That's the main reason I'm not using it.