# how to change document scroll speed in react without jquery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

Is it possible to slow down the scroll speed on certain divs or even just the whole page by using just react?

use refs

Comment: scroll speeds depends on your system settings, seems like you need a custom scroll component for specific dom elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the answer here: [How to window.scrollTo() with a smooth effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261524/how-to-window-scrollto-with-a-smooth-effect)

```
const btn = document.getElementById('elem');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => window.scrollTo({
  top: 400,
  behavior: 'smooth',
}));
```