# window.scrollTo is returning an uncaught typeerror

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

Here is my code

```js
function scroll(ID) {
  var item = document.getElementById(ID);
  var pos = getPosition(item);
  window.scrollTo({
    left: pos['left'], 
    top: pos['top'], 
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="scroll('a')">Scroll</button>

<div id="header" style="height: 200px, background-color: green;">

</div>
<div id="a" style="height: 200px, background-color: red;">

</div>
```

But it returns

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'scroll' on 'Element': The provided value is not of type 'ScrollToOptions'.
    at HTMLHeadingElement.onclick
```

I searched this error but I couldn't find anything that would fix it

Comment: Please make sure you have a [mre].

Comment: Did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261524/how-to-window-scrollto-with-a-smooth-effect