# How to use document.onload in another function?

Tags: javascript, function

I have this function:

```
function myfunc_embed() {
document.onload = function(){
   // myScript
  };
};
```

I call `myfunc_embed()` from a html page. I want this to activate when the html page's DOM is loaded. Looks like it doesn't work. However, if I put settimeout instead of `document.onload()`, it works fine. I am pretty new to JavaScript. Is there something I am missing?

**Note:** It has to be called when DOM is loaded.

**Edit:** The code I am using to call `myfunc_embed()` is here -

`<script src="somewebsite.com/JS/some-func.js"></script>
<script>;myfunc_embed();</script>`

This script is written in a html page inside body element. There is no way I can change the position of the code. 
Full code: https://pastebin.com/f7GSFuNR

Comment: How are you calling `myfunc_embed`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put it in the onload function, the script will work fine without using onload. you just need to call your main function from the HTML

```
  function myfunc_embed(id){
  id.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
     alert("something loaded.");
      });
   }
```

if you want to call a function on loading of a specific element you can simply call the function after declaring the element like this:

```
 <h3 id="yourid">something</h3>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    myfunc_embed('yourid');              
  </script>
```

Comment: We do not know for sure `myfunc_embed` is being called. Best to wait for OP to clarify first.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've edited my question. 
I need to load this when the whole DOM is loaded.

Comment: @AsifurRahman are you calling this function from the head tag?

Comment: @Kashan it's in body tag

Comment: it will most probably show the error "function is not defined" because you are calling is before it is being declared

Comment: @AsifurRahman do you want to call a function on a specific DOM element on loading?

Comment: @Kashan yes. My story is, I don't have access to the core of the website. I want to change an element on their website without changing code in core. I have access to description writing field. It's more like where you write your description in blog websites. It's html supported. And that field loads somewhere in the body tag. Element I want to change with my script is a photo viewer, located before the description field. That element is generated by another JS written on the core of their website and fires on DOM load. I need to wait until the DOM is loaded, wait 200 ms and fire my function.

Comment: it's not possible to make any assumption on this without looking at all the actions related to you code

Comment: i've edited the answer , may be this can solve the problem

Comment: @Kashan Can't use jQuery. Need to use plain JS. Looks like no load/onload is working here

Comment: @Kashan I don't know exactly why it's not working. It's showing me - `Uncaught TypeError: target_div_identifier.addEventListener is not a function`

Comment: See if this can help with this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027935/addeventlistener-is-not-a-function-why-does-this-error-occur

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use the way you have used it 
try this

```
<body onload="myFunction()">


function myFunction(){
   // myScript
  };
```

or you can use a javaScript plugin called Jquery which can do  what you need to to like this

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
   // your script
});
```

in this implementation the code runs when after the whole page has loaded so you don't need to worry about where you put this code that's the beauty of Jquery

Comment: Can't change body html. Have a specific area inside body where I can put the code that calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

If the onload is not getting called, it means you are registering it too late. Check [document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState).

```
function myScript () {
    // ...
}
function myfunc_embed() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        myScript();
    } else {
        document.onload = function () {
            myScript();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this. But unfortunately `myScript();` doesn't fire. I've updated my question, maybe new info will help you.

Comment: `myScript` *will* execute if called. Use `console.log()` to see what executes.