# No errors but JavaScript still doesn't work

Tags: javascript, image

When the user clicks on the like button I want to show a notification above "Mijn verhalen" to let the user know it liked a certain thing. I don't know what's wrong because there are no errors in my JavaScript. But the notification doesn't show up...

This is the JavaScript code:

```js
var een =
  document.getElementsByClassName('like');

var popup =
  document.getElementsByClassName('toevoegen');

een.addEventListener('click', function() {
  popup.classList.toggle('toevoegen');
});
```

```css
img.toevoegen {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5em;
  top: 4em;
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<button class="like"></button>

<img class="toevoegen" src="images/een.png">
```

Comment: I get an error trying to run your code.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a **list** of elements, not just one.

Comment: [Same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027935/addeventlistener-is-not-a-function-why-does-this-error-occur) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32027956/3316645) will work for you as well.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a node list to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var popup = document.getElementsByClassName('toevoegen');
```

document.getElementsByClassName returns **HTMLCollection** which is nothing but array. **classList** is not a known property of **HTMLCollection**.

You need to get the first element of this HTML collection and use the **classList** property. First element is nothing but the popup element.

Or else provide ID to the img tag and access it using document.getElementById which returns a DOM element not an HTML array collection.

```js
var een =
  document.getElementsByClassName('like');

// get the first pop up element here
var popup =
  document.getElementsByClassName('toevoegen')[0];

een.addEventListener('click', function() {
  popup.classList.toggle('toevoegen');
});
```