# I am getting some errors in console while using events

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I was trying click events while I open my browser console I am getting this error: events.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: button.addEventListener is not a function
at events.js:2
(anonymous) @ events.js:2

[Check my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1R8M.png)

Comment: did u checked the variable `button` have the element ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027935/addeventlistener-is-not-a-function-why-does-this-error-occur   check this and remove your question as well. it is duplicate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of all buttons, so if you have only one button you can do `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns an HTML collection. You can either select a specific one using it's index: `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]` or loop through and add an event listener to each one:

```
for (let i of buttons) {
    i.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('CLICK!!!')
    })
}
```