# Uncaught TypeError: c.addEventListener is not a function....? javascript DOM Event

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-item");
console.log("Connected");
console.log(c);
c.addEventListener("click",function(){
  c.textContent = 'X';
})


c.addEventListener("dblclick",function(){
  c.textContent = 'O';
})
```

Why my code is not working the addEventListener function show invalid

Comment: What did you get for this line `console.log(c);` in the console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [".addEventListener is not a function" why does this error occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027935/addeventlistener-is-not-a-function-why-does-this-error-occur)

Answer (score 1):

`.getElementsByClassName()` returns a list of elements.In order to attach an event listener, you need to use a loop or use the index of the element. Please check the below example:

```js
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-item");
    console.log("Connected");
    console.log(c);
    c[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
      c[0].textContent = 'X';
    })


    c[0].addEventListener("dblclick",function(){
      c[0].textContent = 'O';
    })
```

```html
 <div class="grid-item">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("grid-item");` will give you an array of elements that have that, even if there's only 1.

you can use `document.getQuerySelector(".grid-item");` instead and that will give you the single element