# how to store value from radio button using event listener

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, event-listener

When someone clicks on one of the radio buttons I want to get the value of that selected button to be able to store it in a variable.

When I run the code below, it returns the error 'questionOne.addEventListener is not a function.'

```js
{

  const init = () => {

    const questionOne = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="vraag1"]`);

    const valueOne = questionOne.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let selected = document.querySelector(`input[type="radio"]:checked`);
      return selected.value;
    });

  };

  init();

}
```

```html
<section class="question__one">
  <h2 class="question__title ">1. Hoeveel mensen heb je vrolijk gemaakt met je heldendaad?</h2>

  <form class="options__one" method="get" action="zelftest.html">
    <div class="options__div">
      <input class="input__hidden" type="radio" id="optie1" name="vraag1" value="1">
      <label for="optie1">Alleen mezelf</label>
    </div>
    <div class="options__div">
      <input class="input__hidden" type="radio" id="optie2" name="vraag1" value="2">
      <label for="optie2">Minder dan 5</label>
    </div>
    <div class="options__div">
      <input class="input__hidden" type="radio" id="optie3" name="vraag1" value="3">
      <label for="optie3">Tussen 5 en 10 mensen</label>
    </div>
    <div class="options__div">
      <input class="input__hidden" type="radio" id="optie4" name="vraag1" value="4">
      <label for="optie4">Meer dan 10</label>
    </div>
  </form>

</section>
```

Comment: Hey, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027935/addeventlistener-is-not-a-function-why-does-this-error-occur

Answer (score 0):

Use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to add a handler for all radio buttons. You can just retrieve the value of the clicked radio button. The snippet also retrieves the text value of the label for the clicked option.

Using event delegation, you don't have to add an event listener for all `[name=vraag1]`. This prevents the problem you have using `document.querySelectorAll` which returns a [`Nodelist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which either should be looped (`[yourNodeList].forEach`) or, for a single radio button, should be retrieved with `[yourNodeList][index]`.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  console.clear();
  //  event delegation: only act if the click originated from input[type=radio]
  if (evt.target.type === "radio") {
    console.log(`Value: ${evt.target.value}, text: ${
      document.querySelector(`label[for='${evt.target.id}']`).textContent}`);
  }
})
```

```html
<section class="question__one">
  <h2 class="question__title ">1. Hoeveel mensen heb je vrolijk gemaakt met je heldendaad?</h2>

  <form class="options__one" method="get" action="zelftest.html">
    <div class="options__div">
      <input class="input__hidden" type="radio" id="optie1" name="vraag1" value="1">
      <label for="optie1">Alleen mezelf</label>
    </div>
    <div class="options__div">
      <input class="input__hidden" type="radio" id="optie2" name="vraag1" value="2">
      <label for="optie2">Minder dan 5</label>
    </div>
    <div class="options__div">
      <input class="input__hidden" type="radio" id="optie3" name="vraag1" value="3">
      <label for="optie3">Tussen 5 en 10 mensen</label>
    </div>
    <div class="options__div">
      <input class="input__hidden" type="radio" id="optie4" name="vraag1" value="4">
      <label for="optie4">Meer dan 10</label>
    </div>
  </form>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because querySelectorAll will return a collection of occurrences from the HTMl template so it is obvious that you can do that on a collection. Instead, you have to loop through that collection and wire up your event

Or you can you querySelector for a single one and then you can wire up your event

Answer (score 0):

you can only [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to a single element (specific target).

you can loop your `questionOne`

```
const questionOne = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="vraag1"]`);
    questionOne.forEach(item => {
        const valueOne = item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        ...
    });
});
```