# why btn.addEventListener is not a function. i am stuck in this problem and couldn't find any solution .anyone can help me?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, dom-manipulation

** I am learning Dom manipulation and it's my second day...
how can I make it as a function that will generate random index of color which I already stored in my array.
**

```js
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
const color = document.getElementsByClassName("color")


btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const randomNumber = getRandomNumber();

  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber]
  color.textContent = color[randomNumber]
})


function getRandomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Click Me </div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return an array like structure i.e. `HTMLCollection`, so you have to use indexing to get the element as `btn[0].addEventListener...`, You can add `eventListener` on HTMLCollection but on HTMLElements. You should read [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [".addEventListener is not a function" why does this error occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027935/addeventlistener-is-not-a-function-why-does-this-error-occur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `getElementsByClassName` return an array of elements (cf [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)).

to get the first element you should either get the first element of the array `document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0];` or add an id to the button and get it with the `document.getElementById('myButton')` function

```js
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0];
const color = document.getElementsByClassName("color")


btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const randomNumber = getRandomNumber();

  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber]
  color.textContent = color[randomNumber]
})


function getRandomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Click Me </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`getElementsByClassName` will return an array like object of dom elements matching the class. You need to select the entry in this array you want to target :

```
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0];
```

see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) for details

Answer (score -2):

getElementsByClassName returns an array, not a single DOM object. You can try adding an id to the element and use [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)